# How do I access an instance of a class from a static method?

Tags: c#, winforms, static

How can I access a current instance of a class from a static method? The static method is necessary. I just want to get the count of the current child forms of the Parent form. My code is below but it says 'Application' does not exist in the current context

```
private static ReturnOpenWindowCount()
    {
      Form f = (Form)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]
      if(f.Children.Length > 0){//Do Something;}
    }
```

Comment: What is `Application` in your code? A `System.Windows.Forms.Application`? If so, you just missing `using System.Windows.Forms;`.

Comment: We need a little more detail than you have provided here.  I'm inclined to agree with Dmitry; you're just missing a `using` statement.

Comment: have you had any luck getting this to work?

Comment: I just created a static instance of the Form I need to reference. Then in the forms normal constructor I did:


    private static FORMCOPY = this;
So in my static methods it sees FORMCOPY and I can get whatever forms or data I need from that.
Don't know if its the best way to code but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, a static method has no 'current instance'. You could invoke the static method while there are 100 instances around, or 0, and it would work in both cases. It has no relationship to any instances unless you explicitly make one, for example by keeping a private static array of instantiated forms. That would quite likely be bad style and an [XY solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though in relationship to forms.

Answer (score 1):

Youc could pass the `Application` instance in parameters to this method

Comment: I don't think this works.  Most of the methods on Application are `static`, so they're not exposed in the method parameter when it is referenced in code.  Check it in Visual Studio.  `OpenForms` is a static `FormCollection` property, and doesn't show up in Intellisense either, for a parameter of type `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

pass the instance as a parameter. thats as close as you can get..

```
void Main()
{
Foo foo = new Foo();

Foo.ThisFoo(foo);

Console.WriteLine(foo);

Console.ReadLine();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Foo  
{

int x = 0;

public static void ThisFoo(Foo foo)
{
    foo.x = 1;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return "" + x;
}
}
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey but I show you can access private fields